# Could you pls let me know how do i pass variable if the URL is dynamic based on your search value in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

When is search for an item by giving its id the url i get is  http://aa.bb.com/bikes/2 or http://aa.bb.com/bikes/3, 
the value after bikes is dynamic based on my search results and corresponding page is displayed. How do i parameterize this in Jmeter?

I am using HTTP request sampler.
I added a csv config file, gave different ids and added these values in the parameter part and used the parameter variable in the URL path. But it is not working.

EX: the url path i gave as /aa.bb.com/bikes/${id} but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'debug sampler' to narrow down the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the way to do this.
I just mentioned the possible id values in a csv file. 
Used the variable name in the url.
Ex: I created a idValues.csv file and used this file in CSV data set config.
Gave the variable name as value.

now in the HttpSampler in the path i mentioned as http://aa.bb.com/bikes/${value} and it worked.

Thank you.